# momentjs for only time value

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I use momentjs to work with date and time

```
let dateAndTime = moment(component.props.data.value, moment.ISO_8601);
let date = '',
  time = '';
if (dateAndTime) {
  if (moment(dateAndTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()) {
    date = moment(dateAndTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }

  if (moment(dateAndTime, 'HH:mm', true).isValid()) {
    time = moment(dateAndTime).format('HH:mm');
  }
}
```

this code works just fine if `component.props.data.value` contains date and time like `2018-05-22 14:45` or if it contains only date like `2018-05-22`. The problem is sometimes `component.props.data.value` contains only time like `14:45`, so `moment(component.props.data.value, moment.ISO_8601)` doesn't create moment object and code below doesn't execute. Is there any way to handle case only for time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`moment(String, String[])`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/), as the docs says:

> If you don't know the exact format of an input string, but know it could be one of many, you can use an array of formats.
>
> This is the same as [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), only it will try to match the input to multiple formats.

Your first line of code could be like the following:

```
let dateAndTime = moment(component.props.data.value, [moment.ISO_8601, 'HH:mm']);
```